# Find Network location using drive letter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload file locations to my ASP .Net project. This would be so we can track location of all files used for a project. We also like a Hyperlink for each location so we can click and bring up the document.

When I use `<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />` I get drive letter with location. The issue is with using the drive letter in a Hyperlink it will not pull up the directory.

So I need the true location. So instead of H:/ I need \fs1.company.local\Network.

Update:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];
string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath(file.FileName);
```

File name is *Z:/ENG/AutoCAD 2000 stuff/acad.mnr*

And error is

*'Z:/ENG/AutoCAD 2000 stuff/acad.mnr' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.*

Comment: I may not be understanding your question properly, but I think you're looking for Server.MapPath() https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+server.mappath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you used `Server.MapPath(...)` would you be able to do this, however this is dependent on the server having that location mapped.

Your best solution would be to use the fully qualified name `\\server\share\file` if you're working on a domain \ LAN based site.

Comment: Thank you. Trying this now I believe this could be the key/magic!